# pandas.cut day time: how to set a bin from 22:00 to 6:00?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use *pd.cut* to divide 24 hours into the following interval:
`[6,11),[11,14),[14,17),[17,22),[22,6)`
How could I achieve the last bin [22,6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming some form of `datetime` column, try offsetting the `datetime` by 6 hours so that the lower bound becomes midnight. Then cutting based on those hours instead, with the custom labels:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=24, freq='H')
})

df['bins'] = pd.cut((df['datetime'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=6)).dt.hour,
                    bins=[0, 5, 8, 11, 16, 24],
                    labels=['[6,11)', '[11,14)', '[14,17)',
                            '[17,22)', '[22,6)'],
                    right=False)
```

`df`:

```
              datetime     bins
0  2021-01-01 00:00:00   [22,6)
1  2021-01-01 01:00:00   [22,6)
2  2021-01-01 02:00:00   [22,6)
3  2021-01-01 03:00:00   [22,6)
4  2021-01-01 04:00:00   [22,6)
5  2021-01-01 05:00:00   [22,6)
6  2021-01-01 06:00:00   [6,11)
7  2021-01-01 07:00:00   [6,11)
8  2021-01-01 08:00:00   [6,11)
9  2021-01-01 09:00:00   [6,11)
10 2021-01-01 10:00:00   [6,11)
11 2021-01-01 11:00:00  [11,14)
12 2021-01-01 12:00:00  [11,14)
13 2021-01-01 13:00:00  [11,14)
14 2021-01-01 14:00:00  [14,17)
15 2021-01-01 15:00:00  [14,17)
16 2021-01-01 16:00:00  [14,17)
17 2021-01-01 17:00:00  [17,22)
18 2021-01-01 18:00:00  [17,22)
19 2021-01-01 19:00:00  [17,22)
20 2021-01-01 20:00:00  [17,22)
21 2021-01-01 21:00:00  [17,22)
22 2021-01-01 22:00:00   [22,6)
23 2021-01-01 23:00:00   [22,6)
```